# VBA GetObject winmgmts not work after Windows update

Tags: vba, excel, wmi

I have been using Excel VBA to get desktop logon, logoff time from the event log. The program worked well until Windows was updated last week.

After debugging, I figured out the `GetObject` function did not work.

```
Sub get_log_time()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'strComputer = ComputerName
    strComputer = "."

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colLoggedEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile = 'System' and  (EventCode = '7001' or  EventCode = '7002')")

ErrorHandler:
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
     MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
     End If
     Resume Next
End Sub
```

The error message was: "Error # -2147221020 was generated by VBAProject. Error line: 0. Automation Error. Invalid syntax".

I couldn't find why this happens, and how to fix it.

Additional Information:

- I am using Windows 10, Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4549.1000) 32 Bit
- I changed the code to late binding but it still does not work.
- Reference setting: Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

Comment: "Invalid Syntax" sounds very much like a compile error. Please clarify whether the code compiles and runs (and the error is a run-time error).

Comment: @Mat's Mug Thanks for quick reply. It's run-time error. The full message: Error # -2147221020 was generated by VBAProject(my project name). Error line: 0. Automation Error. Invalid systax.

Comment: Ok. Well the error I'm getting (replacing `strComputer` with `Environ$("COMPUTERNAME")`) is run-time error 5 "invalid procedure call or argument", which makes much more sense than "Invalid syntax", which as I said, is a compile error.

Comment: ...and using a dot instead of `Environ$("COMPUTERNAME")` runs without any issues. `set foo = getobject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")` - what's the value of `strComputer`?

Comment: What version of windows?  That line of code (with strComputer replaced with `Environ("COMPUTERNAME")` runs without error here.  `Windows 10.0.15063 Build 15063 / Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.8326.2062) 32-bit`

Comment: The strComputer = "."   I even tried your code above but it still pop the same error

Comment: @Ron: Hi. My computer version: Windows 10.0.15063 Build 15063 / Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4549.1000) 64-bit. So the Excel version is different from yours.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not with the Windows update then?  Unfortunately, I cannot test here using 64bit Excel.  Is `strComputer` the same machine on which this VBA macro is running?  Or maybe the problem is really in another line of the code?

Comment: @Ron: strComputer = ".", so yes it is the same machine on which VBA macro running.

Comment: OK. I cannot reproduce your error and we have the same Windows version.  And I also tried with `strComputer = "."`

Comment: Thank you. I really appriciate. Is there any chance it is because of excel version?

Comment: I suppose.  But there is no way for me to check that. Consider posting the rest of your code, in case that is somehow responsible. If I still cannot reproduce the error, then you'll need to test it in a different version of Excel.

Comment: Hi. I posted the rest of the code to above description. Also, I checked the excel version again, and is was 32bit, not 64bit (I confused excel version with windows). I tested this macro in other computer (windows 10, excel 16.0.4498.1000 32bit) and it worked perfectly. I am truely hopeless now.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here, only with MS Access 2016 32 Bit.
Tested in word too.
Seems to affect all office applications.
I'm running office 32 Bit on Windows 10 64 Bit.

I hope someone can find out what exactly happened here.
This code used to work just fine.

EDIT: The culprit seems to be update KB4011051, after uninstalling the error disappears. I'm looking into it to see if I can find out whether this is by design or a bug.

Comment: Semi-confirmed: see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/zh-CN/e642eac3-e842-4f5b-a774-5516b9bf8474/aug-1-office-update-kb4011051destroys-wmi-access-from-excel?forum=excel